# Import Swiper JS in a Stencil JS web component

Tags: swiper.js, stenciljs

I'm trying to import Swiper JS in a Stencil JS web component.

I've installed Swiper using:
`npm install swiper --save`

In package.json I have:
`"@stencil/core": "^4.0.0", "swiper": "^10.2.0"`

I get an error in the browser console when importing Swiper's `register()` function.

Here is the Stencil web component code:

```
import { Component, Host, h } from '@stencil/core';

import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
register();
// import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-element-bundle.min.js";

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true,
})
export class MyComponent {
  render() {
    return <Host>
      <swiper-container>
        <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
        <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
        <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
      </swiper-container>
    </Host>;
  }
}
```

I get an error in the browser console:

`TypeError: The specifier “swiper/element/bundle” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”. undefined`

This import approach is recommended in Swiper docs and it works fine in an Angular project.

If I replace the `import` and `register()` call with the import from the cdn url, I get no errors and the swiper works fine.

I would like to make the initial import work, if it's possible.

Thanks!